# Mute Music and Mute Sound Buttons

Tags: swift, button, audio, skscene

I am currently putting the finishing touches on an arcade-style game that I am making using Swift and SpriteKit in XCode.

My game has two scenes:

1. a main menu scene where the play button is located
2. a game play scene.

I want to be able to put a node that acts as a button to mute ALL background music across BOTH scenes and a node that acts as a button to mute ALL sound effects across BOTH scenes.

I want BOTH of these buttons to be located on the MAIN MENU SCENE. I have an idea about how to program the button to mute the music/sound-effects but I have no idea how to connect the button across both scenes.

I would also like it to stay muted (or un-muted) even after the user closes the App and re-opens it. Please I really need help with this, and please be specific and straightforward on what I should do because I am new to coding. Overall, I just want to know how to program a node that acts as a button to be able to work across and access properties from two different scenes.

P.S. I am using AVFoundation to run my music and sound effects

Answer (score 0):

i would make the avfoundation audio player a global where ever you set it up

```
  import AVFoundation
    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

then on each viewcontroller ctrl drag and drop the button in as an action

```
 @IBAction func mute(sender: AnyObject) {

    player.volume = 0

}
```

Comment: Im making a game in SpriteKit so i dont think you can ctrl drag and drop a button in can you?